# How can i preserve my Facebook likes when urls change?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, seo, facebook-like

I need to change many urls from my site. 
I have made permanent redirection from the old urls to the new to not lose the google seo.
But some pages have a lot of Facebook likes i would not like to lose.
How can i tell facebook this urls have changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move a URL via 301 redirect and retain the page's Facebook likes and Open Graph information?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o)

Answer (score 0):

On each html page, set the `og:url` meta tag to the url of the original/old place.

Comment: But that way Facebook will update their index? im going to move the web to another server and old urls wont be valid

Comment: Wait a second.  I thought you said you made permanent redirection from the old urls to the new to not lose the google seo.  ??????? huh?

Comment: yes, but it is temporary. I have made the permanent redirection some weeks ago but we plan to move in a week or so to another server. I hope Google to update their indexes before we move and keep the seo.

Comment: I think you'll be screwed if you don't keep the old URLs.

Answer (score -1):

Set a 301 redirect from your old url to your new url.

Comment: That won't help, because the FB scraper follows redirects and takes the result URL as the actual URL.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i made, but i think Facebook did not update the likes in the Facebook index...